[west]: ERROR: update failed for projects: nrfxlib, matter
I am trying to install the Nordic Connect SDK (NCS) using West on Windows via VSCode. First, I install the toolchain, and then this issue arises when I try to download the SDK.

[west]: ERROR: update failed for projects: nrfxlib, matter

I have tried 4,5 times but SDK installation fails.
Nordic documentation recommends installing SDK via VSCode. I have tried a different version to install but the same error is persistent.

Could you explain exactly the commands or buttons you are using to install the SDK?
Do you use the nRF Connect SDK extension for VS Code?

@SigurdHellesvik Yes, I'm using through extension in vscode

Nordic has this tutorial over at https://academy.nordicsemi.com/courses/nrf-connect-sdk-fundamentals/lessons/lesson-1-nrf-connect-sdk-introduction/topic/exercise-1-1/, where they go through the installation steps one at a time. I suggest that you try to follow along with this.

There was internet issue on my side, that is why it was creating problem. Now it is installed.
